# Writing attributes and associated feature class name from file geodatabase to CSV?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, csv, cursor

I need to write a csv file that lists every record from an ID field across all feature classes in a gdb. The code I have written below does that fine, but I also need to write in the second column of the csv which feature class the record was found in.

I have been trying to create the cursor so that it also contains the fc name, then when I use writerow(row) both fields will be printed, but I think this is not a viable approach. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I'm using arcgis 10.2.2

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Data.gdb'
output = r'C:\test.csv'

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fieldnames = ['PropID', 'Feature Class']

with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)
    for fc in fcs:
         with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'PropID','PropID IS NOT NULL') as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                csvwriter.writerow(row)
    del row, cursor
```

Comment: The `csv` library seems to be pure Python and any questions that relate to that may be better researched at [so].  However, if you eliminate that from your code snippet and replace your write statements with `print` then you should have a smaller code snippet that focuses on the point at which you are actually stuck which is how to write/print a feature class name alongside every row created from a cursor on that feature class.

Comment: I realized as I was sending that it might be better in Stack Overflow but Midavalo helped me out anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The csv.writer writes lists to csv, so you need to put your row value and your feature class names into a list before writing to the csv.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Data.gdb'
output = r'C:\test.csv'

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
fieldnames = ['PropID', 'Feature Class']

with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)
    for fc in fcs:
         with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'PropID','PropID IS NOT NULL') as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                outtext = [row[0],fc]
                csvwriter.writerow(outtext)

    del row, cursor
```